# Copy and Rename newest file

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, directory

I want to copy latest file from source path to target Path and then rename as below:

Target Path : C;\User\Client1\FinalReports

Source Path:    C:\User\Client1\Reports\ReportFolderA  (file from Report FolderA should be renamed to target Folder as  File1.csv)
        C:\User\Client1\Reports\ReportFolderB  (file from Report FolderB should be renamed to target Folder as File2.csv)
        C:\User\Client1\Reports\ReportFolderD   (file from Report FolderD should be renamed to target Folder as File4.csv)
        C:\User\Client1\Reports\ReportFolderF  (file from Report FolderF should be renamed to target Folder  as File5.csv)

"C:\User\Client1\Reports" source Path is fixed followed by variable ReportFolderA, ReportFolderB.etc..so we can set only one source path in the script.

I need a script to selecting the path by browsing pop-up method. where I would select only two path "source & target"

By Browsing pop-up because next time I would have different locations, we can not fix them up in once script. I want to run the script as per need to diffident paths.

Comment: I take it by "I want to make a script" you actually mean "I want someone else to make a script for me"?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this for copying the newest file from a folder:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "src=C:\User\Client1\Reports\ReportFolderA"
set "dst=C:\User\Client1\FinalReports"

pushd "%src%"
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a:-d /o:-d') do (
  copy "%%~f" "%dst%\File1.csv"
  goto next
)

:next
popd
```

---

In VBScript you could use the [`Shell.BrowseForFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774065) method for selecting a folder. Example for selecting the source folder:

```
Set os = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
basedir = os.Namespace("C:\").Self.Path
Set fldr = os.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select source folder:", &h10&, basedir)

If fldr Is Nothing Then
  WScript.Echo "User pressed [Cancel]."
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

src = fldr.Self.Path
```

Finding and copying the most recent file in a folder can be achieved like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set mostRecent = Nothing
For Each f In fso.GetFolder(src).Files
  If mostRecent Is Nothing Then
    Set mostRecent = f
  ElseIf f.DateLastModified > mostRecent.DateLastModified Then
    Set mostRecent = f
  End If
Next

If Not mostRecent Is Nothing Then
  mostRecent.Copy fso.BuildPath(dst, "File1.csv")
End If
```

Comment: thx Ansgar...but I want to give paths in a popup asking the source and target path.

Comment: Batch isn't the right tool for that. You may want to consider switching to VBScript.

Comment: oh great...can you please help me to do that?

Comment: I try it it's asking only source path

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers +1 for writing such nice code (to get the source path) that niki niki expect it to get the destination path (and world domination?) too.

Comment: @nikiniki Umm... yes. That's because the example I gave is only for the source path. Obviously you need to do the same for the destination path.

Comment: I set the target path too..But My main concern that is it possible that I give source path till fixed "C:\User\Client1\Reports" the macro automatic goes to the rest part of the source (ReportFolderA,ReportFolderB..etc) & took the lates file and copy to target and rename...if it is possible I would not be define the source path every time.

Comment: @nikiniki You mean you want to prompt for the source path only once and then remember that location? You'll have to save it somewhere then (a config file or the registry for instance), check that place whenever the script is run, and only prompt when there isn't a valid location saved.

Comment: @nikiniki You seem to be mistaking SO for a site where you just specify your requirements (and very incomplete ones at that) while someone else does the actual work for you. That is not [how SO works](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "src=C:\User\Client1\Reports\ReportFolderA"
set "dst=C:\User\Client1\FinalReports"

cd /d "%src%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /od') do set "file=%%~a"
copy "%file%" "%dst%\File1.csv"
```

Comment: I want to give path in a browsing pop-up. also this is not about the only one source there are 4-5 source paths and files needs to be capy and rename.